# MS Excel, List of cell reference depends on one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns od data set

```
A: Names
B: Surname
C: Age
```

now in sheet2, I would reference A2:A6 by =Sheet1!A2 then drag it down, but I need something like if I only change the reference of =Sheet2!A2 to =Sheet1!C2 the below reference should be updated automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, I think U are messing the issue,, please [edit] your post & add some screen shots like scenario before and after. My experience says what you are trying is possible by using VBA macro,, if U are comfortable with it , plz add few lines and the new TAG,, vba also.

Comment: I don't think it's a viable requirement that the formula in your needs is dynamically changing.Only the office 365 version of excel can do this

Comment: it was for analysis, in different price structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this indeed will be much easier on Office 365, we can make a workaround with OFFSET, INDIRECT and CELL functions.

- With OFFSET we'll get the relative cell's value;
- With INDIRECT we'll
  cast a string of a reference to an actual reference;
- With CELL we'll get the row number of the current cell, to calculate the number of rows to search downwards in the OFFSET function.

This is the format to be used:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(#1),CELL("row",#2)-CELL("row",#3),0)
```

**Legend:** 
#1: Address of top cell which holds the data you are looking for. 
#2: Relative reference of the current cell.
#3: Absolute reference (with $) of the first cell in current column.

In the following example, I wrote the function above in cell A5, and coppied it downwards. Here are the results:

[image: Example: Shown result]

And these are the formulas:
[image: Example: Formulas]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with Excel 365.  Pick a cell in a different sheet and enter the spill-down formula:

```
=Sheet1!A2:A6
```

and it will automatically fill down a 5 cell block without dragging:

[image]

Then all you need to do is change the top cell to:

=Sheet1!C2:C6

and the other cells in the block will follow suit.

Comment: I have office 2019, and where this sheet will be running has 2010, this didn't work, thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

What I came across is in range A1:A10 I added

```
=INDIRECT($B$1&0+ROW())
```

then I made a data validation in B1 e.g E, F, now when I select E in B1, it changes data of A1:A10 to E1:E10 and if select F vice versa.

thank you all